# Bootstrap mobile menu wont stay open

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

First question here, thank you for your patience.

I looked for a similar question and was surprised I didn't find one honestly.

I learned enough to create a fiddle for this as well. You can see it here

`https://jsfiddle.net/jhallwebdev/gm6r6mLu/5/`

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row yellow container-fluid">    <!-- YELLOW NAV ROW -->
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <div>
                <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="logo" title="logo" width="100px" height="100px" class="my-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
            <div class="jer-margin-left">
                <div class="header-title">My Bootstrap Site</div>
                <div class="header-slogan">And its navbar problem...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav jer-nav">
                                <li class="jer-active"><a href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FORMS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- END YELLOW NAV ROW -->
</div>  <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

CSS

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    width: 100%;
}

.my-image {
    margin: 10px;
}

.jer-margin-left {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.header-title {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Merriweather;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.header-slogan {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Merriweather;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.no-left-margin {
    margin-left: -70px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    border-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.jer-nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.jer-active {
    border: silver solid 1px;
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .jer-margin-left {
        margin-left: 65px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-title {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .header-slogan {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .jer-margin-left {
        margin-left: 45px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .ph-float-right {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Reduce the size of the output window to force the mobile menu. (instead of the horizontal text menu)

ISSUE 1: To open the mobile menu I am required to click on it twice. That is the first issue.

ISSUE 2: It will not stay open.

In setting up the fiddle I came to believe that its a css issue as when all of the css was stripped away it works as hoped. If I setup the fiddle properly, MY css is in the css window, and the stock bootstrap css is coming in through the external resources options in jsfiddle.

Thank you very much for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is telling the browser to remove it from view, you should remove it:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Bootstrap uses `class="collapse"` and `class="collapse show"` on any `data-toggle="collapse"` element.

You have overridden the ability for `class="collapse show"` to display the element because you have made your style `!important` and also because you have matched the specificity of the bootstrap selectors by also referring to two classes in your selector.

The reason why you had to 'click twice' is because bootstrap adds another class `'collapsing'` to show the transition, and when the element is `'collapse show collapsing'`, it is visible, but when it is only `'collapse collapsing'`, it is not.

Comment: I don't see the collapse-show class anywhere in here. Should it be? I copied the navbar straight from the bootstrap site. Then removed the parts I didn't need. I didn't remove any classes.

Comment: No, those classes are added to the elements by bootstrap's JavaScript. (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

Comment: When I remove that, the opposite happens. The menu is open by default. And when I click to close it, it pops back open.

Comment: @JeremyHall Hmm, I don't get that behaviour when I make that change to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7ou9to4/1/

Comment: After removing the suggested code and one other piece I was able to get it to work properly. I can't remember what the second piece was though. I know that's not helpful. I did get it working properly however. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the fiddler, by removing

```
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
```

Resolves the issue.

In the css remove the above code at `@media (max-width: 1200px)`

I am not able to reproduce ur 1st issue.

**UPDATE**
I'm not sure what you removed. Here is the updated code.

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    width: 100%;
}

.my-image {
    margin: 10px;
}

.jer-margin-left {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.header-title {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Merriweather;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.header-slogan {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Merriweather;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.no-left-margin {
    margin-left: -70px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    border-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.jer-nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.jer-active {
    border: silver solid 1px;
    background-color: rgb(253, 232, 104);
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .jer-margin-left {
        margin-left: 65px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-title {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .header-slogan {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .jer-margin-left {
        margin-left: 45px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .ph-float-right {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I remove that section, the mobile menu is permanently open. I don't want it open by default. If I click it to close, it immediately reopens. Its like the reverse of what was happening before.

Comment: After removing the suggested code and one other piece I was able to get it to work properly. I can't remember what the second piece was though. I know that's not helpful. I did get it working properly however. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just too check
do you have in your html link to bootstrap js?

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes. bootstrap.min.js is in the external resources of the jsfiddle page

Comment: sorry i saw that after i checked - and the above solution is exactly right. in general my practice is not to use bootstrap classes in my own css file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by ensuring I had the same versions of `boostrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` and also ensuring that I loaded jquery before `bootstrap.js`