# How to implement Menu in MVC 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

A MVC 5 project was created and you want to change the menu of this one, for it resorted to [Bootwatch](https://bootswatch.com/), the menu that you want to implement is the following

[image: Menu]

The first thing I did was change the general style of my project, download the bootstrap.css file

[image: Download]

and then I replaced it with my BundleConfig because of the previous one I had, this modifies the style of my project, but does not include the aforementioned navbar

[image: BundleConfig]

To put the Navbar that you want, implement the following code in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Muebles Pangal</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muebles Pangal</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Categorias")">Categorias </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Productoes")">Productos </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Ubicacions")">Proveedores </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Buscar" type="text">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Sistema Bodega</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

But when executing my project I find the following problem, my menu does not work in a good way to the responsive call, this means that when I change (shrink) the size of my browser and call the menu from my `<span class = "navbar- toggler-icon "> </ span>` this is displayed, but it immediately collapses again.

[image: Implementation]

So it does not work in the right way, I've been trying to solve this for days but I have not had good results.
I have installed the Bootstrap and Bootstrap.less packages, could someone help me? what's going on?

any help for me?

Comment: So when you click the button, it shows the menu.. then.. without clicking the button again.. the menu disappears?  Are you able to create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Exactly is that the behavior, you know what's going on? @M12Bennett

Comment: And all you did was copy and paste the code from bootswatch?  no changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing jQuery.min.js i believe, or it might be placed in the wrong order in your code structure. Hope this snippet helps!!

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muebles Pangal</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Categorias ")">Categorias </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Productoes ")">Productos </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Ubicacions ")">Proveedores </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Buscar" type="text">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I don't think it's because of `jQuery.min`.. that's just a minimal version of the normal `jQuery.js`.. which I believe the navbar wouldn't work if that wasn't loaded

Comment: but all i did was add it on top and its working as expected, also if you notice he only has bootstrap.js and no jQuery at all - unless its in a different location

Comment: I don't think the OP is showing us all of their code.. typically by default with a MVC project there is another bundle in the Bundle.config that references jquery.. something like this:  `"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",`

Comment: in that case it might be imported after bootstrap.js is imported. BS website clearly states to place jquery before bs.js. Also its my hunch as this solves the problem. I might be wrong as well :)

Comment: I have tried your answers and it still does not work, how can I provide more information about my problem? @karthik

Comment: run the code snippet in full screen n resize it, its working fine  here. there might be some other script conflicting your toggle functionality. here is the snippet i created for this code https://jsfiddle.net/karthik_kodali/5z27ttru/

Comment: @Klooven I know that.  That's what I meant.

Comment: @M12Bennett Oh oops, sorry, I read wrong! I should probably head to sleep 

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your css for the following:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
```

I am able to get a working menu in a new MVC 5 project using what you posted, but I do not have the same css as you.

Please see a similar problem: [Bootstrap mobile menu wont stay open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989745/bootstrap-mobile-menu-wont-stay-open)